# Spring integration delayer- Jdbc Message Store: message is not getting deleted

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Below  is the delayer code which I am using in my application. The output channel checkMessageInProgress is a database stored procedure call which will check if the message  needs to be processed or delayed.
If the message needs to be delayed again, the retry count is incremented. After 3 delays,  custom Application Exception is raised. I am using a jdbc Message Store for the delayer messages. In scenario where the message is delayed for 3 times and when exception is raised, messages are not getting deleted from the databases tables and the server is picking those messages on restart. How do I make sure that the message is deleted from table in cases where the delay happens for 3 times

```
<int:chain input-channel="delayerChannel"
    output-channel="checkMessageInProgress">
    <int:header-enricher>
    <!-- Exception/ERROR handling for flows originating from Delayer -->
        <int:header name="errorChannel" value="exceptionChannel"
            overwrite="true" />
        <int:header name="retryCount" overwrite="true" type="int"
            expression="headers['retryCount'] == null ? 0 : headers['retryCount'] + 1" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <!-- If retryCount maxed out -discard message and log it in error table -->
    <int:filter expression="(headers['retryCount'] lt 3)"
        discard-channel="raiseExceptionChannel">
    </int:filter>
    <!-- Configurable delay - fetch from property file -->
    <int:delayer id="Delayer" default-delay="${timeout}"
        message-store="mymessageStore">
        <!-- Transaction management for flows originating from the Delayer -->
        <int:transactional transactionmanager="myAppTransactionManager"/>
    </int:delayer>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not surprise. Since you use transactional resource (database) any exception downstream causes transaction rollback, therefore no deletion for the data.

Consider shift message to the separate thread before throwing exception. That way the transaction will be committed.